# Error [Errno 89] Function not implemented while source installing catkin_pkg

Tags: ros, pip, catkin-pkg, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is actually cross-posted on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256336/error-errno-89-function-not-implemented-while-executing-command-python-setup-p) to ask as a general `python` question. Here I ask in `ROS`y way.

On `QNX` realtime OS, I'm trying to install [catkin_pkg](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin_pkg) from source, and seeing the following error upon running `pip`.

```
# pip install -U catkin_pkg 
Downloading/unpacking catkin-pkg
  Running setup.py egg_info for package catkin-pkg
    
Requirement already up-to-date: argparse in /usr/pkg/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from catkin-pkg)
Requirement already up-to-date: docutils in /usr/pkg/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from catkin-pkg)
Requirement already up-to-date: python-dateutil in /usr/pkg/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from catkin-pkg)
Requirement already up-to-date: six in /usr/pkg/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil->catkin-pkg)
Installing collected packages: catkin-pkg
  Running setup.py install for catkin-pkg
    Error [Errno 89] Function not implemented while executing command /usr/qnx650/host/qnx6/x86/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-n130s/catkin-pkg/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-XhRdBe-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 139, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 271, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options, root=options.root_path)
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1185, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 592, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.3-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 627, in call_subprocess
    cwd=cwd, env=env)
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/pkg/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1205, in _execute_child
    self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 89] Function not implemented
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

The first time I ran this `pip` command when the depended components (such as `argparse`, `docutils`, `python-dateutil` and `six`) were not installed, the same error happened too, but not during installation of `catkin_pkg` but while checking these required components are installed. Now that I've installed them one by one, it seems to be happening at while installing `catkin_pkg` itself.

On python's console, `os.fork()`, which I assumed is the root cause, behaves differently. Thus I'm not even sure if the error occurs at `os.fork()` or somewhere different.

```
# python
Python 2.7.4 (default, Jun 21 2013, 22:33:48) 
[GCC 4.4.2] on qnx6
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.fork()
18804790
>>> 0
sem_wait: Invalid argument
```

How can I avoid this error? Thank you!

Using `QNX` 6.5.0 SDP SP1, `pip` version is 1.3 ([its source on github](https://github.com/pypa/pip/tree/1.3/pip))

---

Update) When trying to install `bloom` via `pip` the same error happened.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65754/error-%5Berrno-89%5D-function-not-implemented-while-source-installing-catkin_pkg/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2013-06-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I somehow figured it out. Running `pip` WITHOUT `-U` option gets `catkin_pkg` installed (install log is at the bottom for the reference).

...But why...? Help message of `pip`'s doesn't seem to make sense to me:

```
$ pip install --help
:
Install Options:
:
  -U, --upgrade   Upgrade all packages to the newest available version. This process is recursive irregardless of whether a dependency is already satisfied.
```

Log of installation by `pip`:

```
$ pip install catkin_pkg    
Downloading/unpacking catkin-pkg
  Running setup.py egg_info for package catkin-pkg
    
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): argparse in /usr/pkg/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from catkin-pkg)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): docutils in /usr/pkg/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from catkin-pkg)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil in /usr/pkg/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from catkin-pkg)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six in /usr/pkg/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil->catkin-pkg)
Installing collected packages: catkin-pkg
  Running setup.py install for catkin-pkg
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/catkin_create_pkg from 664 to 775
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/catkin_generate_changelog from 664 to 775
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/catkin_tag_changelog from 664 to 775
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/catkin_test_changelog from 664 to 775
    
    changing mode of /usr/pkg/bin/catkin_create_pkg to 775
    changing mode of /usr/pkg/bin/catkin_generate_changelog to 775
    changing mode of /usr/pkg/bin/catkin_tag_changelog to 775
    changing mode of /usr/pkg/bin/catkin_test_changelog to 775
Successfully installed catkin-pkg
Cleaning up...
```

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0